# Create new container with interactive shell

Tags: node.js, shell, docker

I wanted to create a new container with Node.js and start a bash-shell in it where I can interactively verify something.

Therefore I did `docker run node /bin/bash` but it exited instantly. 
What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the -it: `docker run -it <image-name> /bin/bash`

> --interactive, -i: Keep STDIN open even if not attached
>
> --tty, -t: Allocate a pseudo-TTY

[docker run reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#overriding-dockerfile-image-defaults)

Comment: oh, how could I forget that :)